# su: cannot set groups operation not permitted on rhel 7

Tags: chmod, rhel7, su

By mistake we did chmod 777 on all directories of our rhel 7 server. Now we are trying to do su root from a different user but we are getting the following error **su: cannot set groups: Operation not permitted**.

Please let me know what steps i can follow to rectify the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
chmod 4755 /bin/su
```

After executing above command i was able to do login as su from normal user (after chmod 777 for all directories).